# Lua functions use "self" in source but no metamethod allows to use them

Tags: list, oop, lua

I've been digging into Lua's source code, both the C source from their website and the lua files from Lua on Windows. I found something odd that I can't find any information about, as to why they chose to do this.

There are some methods in the string library that allows OOP calling, by attaching the method to the string like this:

```
string.format(s, e1, e2, ...)
s:format(e1, e2, ...)
```

So I dug into the source code for the module table, and found that functions like `table.remove()`, also allows for the same thing.

Here's the source code from **UnorderedArray.lua**:

```
function add(self, value)
    self[#self + 1] = value
end

function remove(self, index)
    local size = #self
    if index == size then
        self[size] = nil
    elseif (index > 0) and (index < size) then
        self[index], self[size] = self[size], nil
    end
end
```

Which indicate that the functions should support the colon method. Lo' and behold when I copy **table** into my new list, the methods carry over. Here's an example using table.insert as a method:

```
function copy(obj, seen) -- Recursive function to copy a table with tables
  if type(obj) ~= 'table' then return obj end
  if seen and seen[obj] then return seen[obj] end

  local s = seen or {}
  local res = setmetatable({}, getmetatable(obj))
  s[obj] = res
  for k, v in pairs(obj) do res[copy(k, s)] = copy(v, s) end
  return res
end

function count(list) -- Count a list because #table doesn't work on keyindexed tables
  local sum = 0; for i,v in pairs(list) do sum = sum + 1 end; print("Length: " .. sum)
end

function pts(s) print(tostring(s)) end -- Macro function

local list = {1, 2, 3}
pts(list.insert) --> nil

pts(table["insert"]) --> function: 0xA682A8
pts(list["insert"]) --> nil

list = copy(_G.table)
pts(table["insert"]) --> function: 0xA682A8
pts(list["insert"]) --> function: 0xA682A8

count(list) --> Length: 9

list:insert(-1, "test")

count(list) --> Length: 10
```

Was Lua 5.1 and newer supposed to support table methods like the string library but they decided to not implement the meta method?

**EDIT:**

I'll explain it a little further so people understand.
Strings have metamethods attached that you can use on the strings OOP style.

```
s = "test"
s:sub(1,1)
```

But tables doesn't. Even though the methods in the table's source code allow for it using "self" functions. So the following code doesn't work:

```
t = {1,2,3}
t:remove(#t)
```

The function has a *self* member defined in the argument (UnorderedArray.lua:25: function remove(self,index)).

You can find the metamethods of strings by using:

```
for i,v in pairs(getmetatable('').__index) do
  print(i, tostring(v))
end
```

which prints the list of all methods available for strings:

```
sub     function: 0xB4ABC8
upper   function: 0xB4AB08
len     function: 0xB4A110
gfind   function: 0xB4A410
rep     function: 0xB4AD88
find    function: 0xB4A370
match   function: 0xB4AE08
char    function: 0xB4A430
dump    function: 0xB4A310
gmatch  function: 0xB4A410
reverse function: 0xB4AE48
byte    function: 0xB4A170
format  function: 0xB4A0F0
gsub    function: 0xB4A130
lower   function: 0xB4AC28
```

If you attach the module/library *table* to a table like Oka showed in the example, you can use the methods that *table* has just the same way the string metamethods work.

The question is: Why would Lua developers allow metamethods of strings by default but tables doesn't even though table's library and it's methods allow it in the source code?

The question was answered: It would allow a developer of a module or program to alter the metatables of all tables in the program, leading to the result where a table would behave differently from vanilla Lua when used in a program. It's different if you implement a class of a data type (say: vectors) and change the metamethods of that specific class and table, instead of changing all of Lua's standard table metamethods. This also slightly overlaps with operator overloading.

Comment: I have read it couple of times now but I still don't get what is this question about. I'm used to being stupid but this one just bothers me. Where is the problem? **Table** is not implemented like **String** because you don't want it in all of your tables usually.

Comment: If it helps, it was  "[a metatable for strings](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4)" and the applicability of metatables to types other than "table" and "userdata" that were added in 5.1.

Comment: @TomBlodget: Yes, strings has metatables natively, but tables has metamethods that are not assigned as metamethods to new tables.

Comment: @Mossarelli To solve a little confusion: Functions like `gsub` and `rep` are not what you would call a _metamethod_. Metamethods are those found on _metatables_, and are double underscore prefixed; `__index`, `__len`, `__newindex`. They can be found in [Section 2.4 of the Lua manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4). e.g., string instances have a _metatable_ with an `__index` _metamethod_, which points to the `string` table.

Comment: @Oka, right. It feels funny calling an __index or __newindex table a metamethod but it works as shorthand and is documented.

Comment: @Oka It's still useful for people to understand that strings have methods attached based on their type. There are some things with Lua that isn't plainly documented and predictable.

Comment: [The string library provides all its functions inside the table `string`. It also sets a metatable for strings where the `__index` field points to the `string` table. Therefore, you can use the string functions in object-oriented style…](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're asking why it is not possible to do the following:

```
local tab = {}
tab:insert('value')
```

Having tables spawn with a default metatable and `__index` breaks some assumptions that one would have about tables.

Mainly, empty tables should be *empty*. If tables were to spawn with an `__index` metamethod lookup for the `insert`, `sort`, etc., methods, it would break the assumption that an empty table should not respond to any members.

This becomes an issue if you're using a table as a cache or memo, and you need to check if the `'insert'`, or `'sort'` strings exist or not (think arbitrary user input). You'd need to use `rawget` to solve a problem that didn't need to be there in the first place.

Empty tables should also be *orphans*. Meaning that they should have no relations without the programmer explicitly giving them relations. Tables are the only complex data structure available in Lua, and are the foundation for a lot of programs. They need to be free and flexible. Pairing them with the the `table` table as a default metatable creates some inconsistencies. For example, not all tables can make use of the generic `sort` function - a weird cruft for dictionary-like tables.

Additionally, consider that you're utilizing a library, and that library's author has told you that a certain function returns a densely packed table (i.e., an array), so you figure that you can call `:sort(...)` on the returned table. What if the library author has changed the metatable of that return table? Now your code no longer works, and any generic functions built on top of a `_:sort(...)` paradigm can't accept these tables.

---

Basically put, strings and tables are two very different beasts. Strings are immutable, static, and their contents are *predictable*. Tables are mutable, transient, and very *unpredictable*.

It's much, much easier to add this in when you need it, instead of baking it into the language. A very simple function:

```
local meta = { __index = table }

_G.T = function (tab)
    if tab ~= nil then
        local tab_t = type(tab)

        if tab_t ~= 'table' then
            error(("`table' expected, got: `%s'"):format(tab_t), 0)
        end
    end

    return setmetatable(tab or {},  meta)
end
```

Now any time you want a table that responds to functions found in the `table` table, just prefix it with a `T`.

```
local foo = T {}

foo:insert('bar')

print(#foo) --> 1
```

Comment: A simple example why having a default metatable would be bad: Consider the code `mytbl = {}; mytbl[io.read()] = "asdf"; mytbl:insert(123)` where the user types "insert". Now `mytbl.insert` is the string "asdf", leading to an error when you try to call it.

Comment: Brilliant answer. There was a method to add table and it's methods as a metatable, I just didn't find the documentation on it.

Comment: `getmetatable(foo).__index` now returns _table's_ methods. Brilliant.